# using a gre tunnel as default route

Tags: ip, tunneling, route, openwrt, gre

I have two private networks (A, B) that connects via another company's private network (C). Network A has internet access. I want to make a tunnel between B and A that goes through C. Then network B will use A as default route for internet access.

Network A: 10.20.0.0/24, on C: 10.10.15.3
Network B: 10.20.1.0/24, on C: 192.168.25.3

10.10.15.3 can access 192.168.25.3 and vice versa

Network A tunnel script:

> ip tunnel add tunnel0 mode gre local 10.10.15.3 remote 192.168.25.3 ttl 64
>   ip link set tunnel0 up
>   ip addr add 10.20.200.1/30 peer 10.20.200.2/30 dev tunnel0
>   ip route add 10.20.1.0/24 via 10.20.200.2

Network B tunnel:

> ip tunnel add tunnel0 mode gre local 192.168.25.3 remote 10.10.15.3 ttl 64
>   ip link set tunnel0 up
>   ip addr add 10.20.200.2/30 peer 10.20.200.1/30 dev tunnel0
>   ip route add 10.20.0.0/24 via 10.20.200.1
>   ip r d default && ip r a default via 10.20.200.1

From GW on network B:

> traceroute to 10.20.0.1 (10.20.0.1), 30 hops max, 38 byte packets
>    1  10.20.0.1 (10.20.0.1)  4.685 ms  4.505 ms  4.478 ms
>
> traceroute to 10.20.0.14 (10.20.0.14), 30 hops max, 38 byte packets
>    1  10.20.200.1 (10.20.200.1)  4.643 ms  4.387 ms  4.555 ms
>    2  10.20.200.1 (10.20.200.1)  4.423 ms  4.473 ms  4.437 ms
>
> traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 30 hops max, 38 byte packets
>    1  10.20.200.1 (10.20.200.1)  4.595 ms  4.461 ms  4.628 ms
>    2  10.20.200.1 (10.20.200.1)  4.476 ms  4.521 ms  4.536 ms

something's not right.... but why?

Comment: You cannot allow a tunnel to become the route to its own destination or the tunnel implodes.

Comment: No, but I can set the default route via the tunnel since 10.10.15.3 and 192.168.25.3 talks directly to each other via the bridge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lol

I forgot to accept FORWARD by default on 10.10.15.3 :(